# Why doesn't this argo workflow run?

Tags: argo-workflows

I am trying to configure my Argo workflows.

I know how to correct an error, but how do I debug if they do not run?

I am running Argo 3.0.10 on Ubuntu 20.04

```
argo: v3.0.10
  BuildDate: 2021-08-18T23:41:44Z
  GitCommit: 0177e73b962136200517b7f301cd98cfbed02a31
  GitTreeState: clean
  GitTag: v3.0.10
  GoVersion: go1.16.6
  Compiler: gc
  Platform: linux/amd64
```

I apply the below YAML using the following command

argo submit test.yaml --watch:

```
{
   "apiVersion": "argoproj.io/v1alpha1",
   "kind": "Workflow",
   "metadata": {
      "annotations": {
         "argo": "workflows"
      },
      "generateName": "hello-world-",
      "labels": {
         "workflows.argoproj.io/archive-strategy": "false"
      },
      "namespace": "argo"
   },
   "spec": {
      "entrypoint": "entrypoint",
      "parallelism": 3,
      "podGC": {
         "strategy": "OnWorkflowSuccess"
      },
      "securityContext": {
         "fsGroup": 2000,
         "runAsGroup": 3000,
         "runAsNonRoot": true,
         "runAsUser": 1000
      },
      "serviceAccountName": "argouser",
      "templates": [
         {
            "container": {
               "args": [
                  "hello world"
               ],
               "command": [
                  "cowsay"
               ],
               "image": "docker/whalesay:latest",
               "resources": {
                  "limits": {
                     "cpu": "100m",
                     "memory": "32Mi"
                  }
               }
            },
            "name": "entrypoint"
         }
      ],
      "ttlStrategy": {
         "secondsAfterSuccess": 5
      }
   }
}
```

As far as I can tell, the pods are never created and there is no record of them, however, the workflow exists. Here is the output of kubectl describe for the workflow:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  annotations:
    argo: workflows
  creationTimestamp: "2021-09-07T20:48:37Z"
  generateName: hello-world-
  generation: 1
  labels:
    workflows.argoproj.io/archive-strategy: "false"
  name: hello-world-p6h4k
  namespace: argo
  resourceVersion: "14801149"
  uid: ee28ae8d-970e-47c6-83ee-fcdc6db44c39
spec:
  arguments: {}
  entrypoint: entrypoint
  parallelism: 3
  podGC:
    strategy: OnWorkflowSuccess
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: 2000
    runAsGroup: 3000
    runAsNonRoot: true
    runAsUser: 1000
  serviceAccountName: argouser
  templates:
  - container:
      args:
      - hello world
      command:
      - cowsay
      image: docker/whalesay:latest
      name: ""
      resources:
        limits:
          cpu: 100m
          memory: 32Mi
    inputs: {}
    metadata: {}
    name: entrypoint
    outputs: {}
  ttlStrategy:
    secondsAfterSuccess: 5
status:
  finishedAt: null
  startedAt: null
```

and the "error" message is:

```
Name:                hello-world-p6h4k
Namespace:           argo
ServiceAccount:      argouser
Status:              Pending
Created:             Tue Sep 07 20:48:37 +0000 (now)
Progress:
FATA[2021-09-07T20:48:37.186Z] workflows.argoproj.io "hello-world-p6h4k" not found
```

Comment: Can you post 1) the version of Argo Workflows you're running, 2) the original YAML for the workflow you've submitted, and 3) the exact commands you're using to submit the workflow and check its status?

Comment: @MichaelCrenshaw Thank you.  I have posted that information above.

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret the "not found" error, given that `describe` works. Have you tried following up with an `argo list` and/or reading the workflow controller logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Michael Crenshaw for the tips!

I looked at the workflow-controller-logs and the workflow did run successfully, but did not output any argo logs and the workflow is still listed as pending. I am still looking for the correct configuration, so I am not certain how these messages are inconsistent.  If I find the answer, I will post it here.

Comment: Try `kubectl get po -n argo`. If there's a pod with a similar name to that workflow, describe it. There might be a hint in the events. For example, the ServiceAccount might not have sufficient permissions.

Comment: I wrote a thingy that might help: https://dev.to/crenshaw_dev/how-to-debug-an-argo-workflow-31ng

Comment: @Michael Crenshaw - Nice tutorial :)   There were no associated pods listed under kubectl get po -n argo.  Now that I think about it, however, it may be because I have the workflows clean up after themselves if successful.  I will have to remember that for future debugging

Comment: Thanks! Yep, cleanup could be getting rid of the pods... but if I understand correctly, the workflow never leaves Pending state, so it seems weird that the cleanup stuff (which appears to trigger only for successful workflows) would be deleting the pods.

Comment: My current hypothesis is that my permissions settings do not allow updates to the CLI. Do you know if this is a separate permission that needs to be granted and, if so, what it might be?

Comment: Interesting... I'm not sure exactly what mechanism the CLI uses to retrieve those logs, but I could imagine it being a permissions issue. I think the first place I'd start is by running the workflow with all the GC/TTL stuff removed, so we can be certain whether any pods are actually being created.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for  "error" message is ommited namespace for cli command, try this instead:

```
argo submit test.yaml --watch -n argo
```

And then you can check your Workflow CRD object, it contains error message. Possibly you need to set proper `serviceAccountName` and `namespace` in your `test.yaml`

Comment: Argo can be configured to handle workflows in any namespace. And by default it will use the default serviceaccount in the namespace in which the workflow was submitted. But yes, there are circumstances where specifying these will resolve a broken workflow.